# curl_exec maximum execution time - what is causing it?

Tags: php, xml, curl

I get the dreaded message:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 90 seconds exceeded in /home/pricing.php on line 239
```

the code is:

```
$url = "http://*******.com/feed?f=PR&categories=$cat_id&limit=100&startproducts=$ii&price_min=0.01&sortproducts=score&show=properties";

$c = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "****:****");
$xml = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($c)); // line 239
```

the simplexml_load_string is line 239, surely this means the feed has been got (for want of a better word!) and the string is being loaded, but surely that can't take more than 90 seconds?

My questions are:

1 - what could/would cause this?

2 - is it safe to increase the `php_value max_execution_time` above 90 secs and what's considered a safe maximum?

3 - is there a better/faster/more stable way to bring down the feed than using curl?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: No, it doesn't mean the stream "has been got". The time could very well be spent in `curl_exec` if the website is "slow". Break that into two lines if you want to be sure.

Comment: Ah ok - so if i break it down like:

$feed = curl_exec($c);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($feed);

Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, then you'll know which of the two calls is stalling.

Comment: use "retrieved" for better word of "got"

Answer (score 11):

A1:
Yes, you got your answer from your 2nd question. it's caused by php's `max_execution_time`.

A2:
It's not safe, unless you are hosting it locally and you know what your script is doing. I think the common practice is either 30sec or max 300sec(5min).

A3
If you are dealing with curl, I prefer you to set `set_time_limit(0)` on very top of your php script(code level equivalent for `max_execution_time` in `php.ini`), and use the timeout for curl to handle the timeout.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 2000); //in miliseconds
```

Comment: RE A3 - does this then mean the script would not fail if i set CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS - if so this is a better option

Comment: If you are referring **fail** as in the php execution timeout, then the answer is yes, it won't fail as long as set_time_limit is very high or 0(unlimited). I can't remember the exact detail when it hits the `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS`, but one thing for sure is that `curl_exec($c)` will return empty string. So, just do a simple check before you parsing to your `simplexml_load_string`.

Answer (score 2):

1. The curl to external feed is extremely slow
2. Is OK to increase the max_execution_time to a higher value, but is not recommended. If the script is to serve as one of your normal web pages, you have to think twice. No user would like to wait for more than 90 seconds to get a page loaded.
3. Cache it!

Details of cache it! :-

Not a super logic,
what it mean is you can prepare list of the feed URL,
then do a background job (cronjob) to grab each feed URL and store into local storage.
Once the local XML is available, load from local

So, is reverse of on-demand access, get the XML ready before any user would access the page.
The difficulties will be lots of different feed URL to grab, there is an [curl_multi_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) which should be ideal to grab multiple url at the same time.